# calling c from php

Tags: php, c

I was wondering if there was a way to call existing C code from php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your C code is compiled to an executable, that executable can be executed from PHP -- but I'm guessing this is not quite what you meant ?

If you want to excute C code from PHP : that is not possible... unless you compile your C code to a PHP extension.

A PHP extension is like a `.dll`, on windows : it's a library, that can export functions that can be called from PHP.

If you want to learn more about writing PHP extensions, those links will probably interest you :

- [Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/)
- [Extension Writing Part II: Parameters, Arrays, and ZVALs](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1022-Extension-Writing-Part-II-Parameters-Arrays-and-ZVALs)
- [Extension Writing Part II: Parameters, Arrays, and ZVALs [continued]](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1023-Extension-Writing-Part-II-Parameters-Arrays-and-ZVALs-continued)
- [Extension Writing Part III: Resources](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1024-Extension-Writing-Part-III-Resources)
- And, just for reference, as i'ts about C++ and not C : [Wrapping C++ Classes in a PHP Extension](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486-Wrapping-C-Classes-in-a-PHP-Extension)

And, if you are **really** interested by the subject, and ready to spend some money on it, you could buy the book [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) *([some pages are available as preview on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=zMbGvK17_tYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Extending+and+Embedding+PHP&ei=KqeOSoeML4bMM4aL3LAH#v=onepage&q=&f=false) too)* ; It's considered as **the** book to read when interested on this subject *(In fact, I've bought it some time ago, and, in my opinion, it is indeed an interesting read)*

BTW, the author of that book is also the author of the first four articles I linked to ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486) article talks about PHP-C++ bindings. May be of help. In particular, checkout the BEGIN_EXTERN_C/END_EXTERN_C macros.