# PHP: How To Call Standard Library Functions

Tags: php, c, function, call

I'm starting with PHP for dynamic web pages. I have some libraries written in ANSI C for getting/setting parameters and other proprietary stuff. I wonder, is there a simple solution to use a wrapper inside PHP to call this functions? Is there a already existing class/library? What would be the best practice to do this on my own? I don't want do make calls to external applications and use stdin/stdout!

Is there a simple example available? I don't want to dig through the Zend documentation for now, I only need a feeling for the complexity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C/C++ library function from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you package your libraries into a DLL? If so, you can call them through PHP's COM api.

PHP COM Docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

Example Code:

```
<?php  
$com = new COM("DynamicWrapper");
$com->Register("KERNEL32", "Beep", "i=ll", "f=s", "r=l");
$com->Beep(800, 10);
```

Otherwise you can write a extension that contains a custom wrapper function (ie, execute_through_wrapper('yourfunc')). Here is a doc on writing php functions in C.

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.funcs.php

**Edit:**
http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2008/12/php-extensions-how-and-why/

Here is a quick tutorial on writing extensions in C. It shouldn't be too difficult to write a wrapper function. Once you created the extension, it can be loaded dynamically through `dl()` (very dangerous, and depreciated).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Those are the only options in your case. There isn't a linux equivalent (.so loader) of the dll loader (its a win32-related api call).

Comment: I forgot to mention, our operating system is Linux for this project. But it should be possible to build a shared library for this libs.

Comment: Thanks John, it took a while to read this articles, and I guess writing an extension is not too complicated!

Comment: you can very easily write an extension for your library in C, should be a 15 min work if only you need to do is get some data by calling methods of your c library.....

Answer (score 2):

You could also have [gearman](http://gearman.org/) act as an intermediary.

> Gearman provides a generic application
>   framework to farm out work to other
>   machines or processes that are better
>   suited to do the work. It allows you
>   to do work in parallel, to load
>   balance processing, and to call
>   functions between languages. It can be
>   used in a variety of applications,
>   from high-availability web sites to
>   the transport of database replication
>   events. In other words, it is the
>   nervous system for how distributed
>   processing communicates.

Comment: Wow - this is comletely new to me! It looks like a lightweight RPC client/server framework, isn't it? Maybe a little bit of overkill for a small application, but for a complex system it might be very useful. An I can use it for communication between multiple processes, written in PHP, C, C++, etc?

Answer (score 1):

What'a about SWIG? http://www.swig.org/

Answer (score 0):

At http://pear.php.net/ I found an extension named "inline_c". Unfortunately I is not maintained. But it looks like this would be the kinde of stuff I would prefer.