# How to get list of all cached items by key in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, key

The Cache class in laravel has methods such as get('itemKey') to retrieve items from the cache, and remember('itemKey', ['myData1', 'myData2']) to save items in the cache.

There is also a method to check if an item exists in the cache: Cache::has('myKey');

Is there any way, (when using the file-based cache driver), to get a list of all items in the cache?

For instance, something that might be named something like "Cache::all()" that would return:

```
[
    'itemKey' => [
        'myData1',
        'myData2'
   ],
   'myKey' => 'foo'
]
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to loop through all possible key names using the Cache::has() method. i.e. aaa, aab, aac, aad... but of course, this is not a solution.

I can't see anything in the documentation or the API that describes a function like this, but I don't think its unreasonable to believe that one must exist.

Comment: What caching backend are you using ? Redis? Memcached? or ?

Comment: File cache. I've read there is a function like the one I describe for Memcached, and that there is the option of using tags. But I need to use file as its a lot of data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to do that using **Cache** facade. Its interface represents the functionality that **all** underlying storages offer and some of the stores do not allow listing all keys.

If you're using the **FileCache**, you could try to achieve that by interacting with the underlying storage directly. It doesn't offer the method you need, so you'll need to iterate through the cache directory. It won't be too efficient due to a lot of disk I/O that might need to happen.

In order to access the storage, you need to do

```
$storage = Cache::getStore(); // will return instance of FileStore
$filesystem = $storage->getFilesystem(); // will return instance of Filesystem

$keys = [];
foreach ($filesystem->allFiles('') as $file1) {
  foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($file1) as $file2) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, $filesystem->allFiles($file1 . '/' . $file2));
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41566729/539149 for version that worked for me in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 16):

Older answers didn't work for me in Laravel 5.2 so I used this solution:

```
    $storage = \Cache::getStore(); // will return instance of FileStore
    $filesystem = $storage->getFilesystem(); // will return instance of Filesystem
    $dir = (\Cache::getDirectory());
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($dir) as $file1) {

        if (is_dir($file1->getPath())) {

            foreach ($filesystem->allFiles($file1->getPath()) as $file2) {
                $keys = array_merge($keys, [$file2->getRealpath() => unserialize(substr(\File::get($file2->getRealpath()), 10))]);
            }
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: On my server I found they were not in another dir, so would need the else {} 
$keys = array_merge($keys, [$file1->getRealpath() => unserialize(substr(\File::get($file1->getRealpath()), 10))]);

Comment: This was on Laravel 5.3, as jedrzej.kurylo would not work, this did though

Answer (score 12):

In *'yourKeyGoesHere'* you can insert a string used as same as a like with a * or insert directly the exactly key.

```
 $redis = Cache::getRedis();
 $a_keys = $redis->keys("*yourKeyGoesHere*");
 foreach ($a_keys as $key){
    //Your Action ...
    //For example forget key
    $redis->del($key);
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Work with Redis I think, but... please explain ? what is *yourKeyGoesHere* ?

Comment: $redis->keys('*'); Will get you all the keys

Comment: `Cache::getRedis()` doesn't work (Laravel 8), `Cache::driver()` works but you get an instance of _Illuminate\Cache\Repository_ and it doesn't seem to provide a method to get the whole cache content.

Comment: If this doesn't return anything, or not what you expect, it helps to remember that you might have several Redis connections configured, and this answer uses the default connection. @Yevgeniy Afanasyev's answer reminded me of that, and with the right connection it now works (to my defense: the connections were configured by someone else :) ).

Answer (score 9):

For Memcached, you can do this:

```php
cache()->getMemcached()->getAllKeys()
```

1. get `Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager`
2. Get `Memcached`: http://php.net/manual/de/class.memcached.php
3. `getAllKeys()`: http://php.net/manual/de/memcached.getallkeys.php

This gives you an array of keys you can go through.

Comment: Short, straight to the point. Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

in `\config\database.php` make a redis store for the cache

```
   // store cache in their own redis store ...
    'cache-connection' => [
        'host'               => ...,
        'password'           => ...,
        'port'               => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database'           => 2,
        'read_write_timeout' => 60,
        'timeout'            => 6.0,
    ],
```

in `\config\cache.php` use this redis database

```
'stores' => [
   ...
   'redis' => [
        'driver'     => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache-connection',
    ],
],
```

now you can use Redis class to check what is in your cache

```
$a = Redis::connection('cache-connection')->keys('*');
\Log::debug($a);
```

Comment: I tried following this advice but am getting stuck on the part where I get the values from the keys: [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959859/get-all-the-values-that-ive-set-using-cacheput)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to look at the Redis connection configuration in database.php! I was trying to use one of the other answers, which didn't work because the data I wanted was only available with a non-default connection.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**

```php
// Add Namespace
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
```

**Step 2**

```php
// Get All Available Keys
$cacheKeys = Redis::connection('cache')->keys('*');
```

**Step 3**

```php
// Laravel DDD
ddd($cacheKeys);
```

*OR*

```php
// PHP Variable Dump
var_dump($cacheKeys);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this answer was [already given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860052/php-how-to-call-standard-library-functions) and does not need to be repeated.

Comment: @miken32 there is nothing on your link, his answer is very helpful.

Comment: @Tahola obviously wrong link, probably meant this one, another answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58514663/1255289

Comment: This Can be done using Redis but in my case, I'm using laravel cache and I'm not sure I'll use Redis as a cache.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I ran into the issue the other day and couldn't find a solution anywhere for the file storage system.

My use case was that I wanted to be able to remove based on the naming convention of full stops seperating groups. For example `cache()->forget('foo')` wouldn't remove the key `foo.bar`.

The way it works is it keeps a json encoded array of all the keys you add to the file store, then when you want to remove it loops through and if it matches it is removed. This may be useful to you as well but if not your use case could utilize the `cache()->getKeys()` method which now works too.

**Steps to follow:**

In your `AppServiceProvider.php` `register` method add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use App\Extensions\FileStore;
...
$this->app->booting(function () {
    Cache::extend('file', function ($app) {
        return Cache::repository(new FileStore($app['files'], config('cache.stores.file.path'), null));
    });
});
```

Then create a new directory in `app` called `Extensions`. Add a new file in the new `Extensions` directory called `FileStore.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

class FileStore extends \Illuminate\Cache\FileStore
{
    /**
     * Get path for our keys store
     * @return string
     */
    private function keysPath()
    {
        return storage_path(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ['framework','cache','keys.json']));
    }

    /**
     * Get all keys from our store
     * @return array
     */
    public function getKeys()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->keysPath())) {
            return [];
        }

        return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->keysPath()), true) ?? [];
    }

    /**
     * Save all keys to file
     * @param  array $keys
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveKeys($keys)
    {
        return file_put_contents($this->keysPath(), json_encode($keys)) !== false;
    }

    /**
     * Store a key in our store
     * @param string $key [description]
     */
    private function addKey($key)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeys();

        // Don't add duplicate keys into our store
        if (!in_array($key, $keys)) {
            $keys[] = $key;
        }

        $this->saveKeys($keys);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // LARAVEL METHODS
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Store an item in the cache for a given number of seconds.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  int  $seconds
     * @return bool
     */
    public function put($key, $value, $seconds)
    {
        $this->addKey($key);
        return parent::put($key, $value, $seconds);
    }

    /**
     * Remove an item from the cache.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function forget($forgetKey, $seperator = '.')
    {
        // Get all stored keys
        $storedKeys = $this->getKeys();

        // This value will be returned as true if we match at least 1 key
        $keyFound = false;

        foreach ($storedKeys as $i => $storedKey) {
            // Only proceed if stored key starts with OR matches forget key
            if (!str_starts_with($storedKey, $forgetKey.$seperator) && $storedKey != $forgetKey) {
                continue;
            }

            // Set to return true after all processing
            $keyFound = true;

            // Remove key from our records
            unset($storedKeys[$i]);
            
            // Remove key from the framework
            parent::forget($storedKey);
        }

        // Update our key list
        $this->saveKeys($storedKeys);

        // Return true if at least 1 key was found
        return $keyFound;
    }
    
    /**
     * Remove all items from the cache.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function flush()
    {
        $this->saveKeys([]);
        return parent::flush();
    }
}
```