# How can I determine all existing cache keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

How can I determine all existing cache keys in a project built with Laravel framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of all cached items by key in Laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791178/how-to-get-list-of-all-cached-items-by-key-in-laravel-5)

Comment: which cache drive are you using?

Comment: @CanCelik File Cache.

Comment: This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31791530/2951316

Answer (score 1):

There is a no way to do this via Laravel Cache library. But you can try to get the keys directly from the cache storage (filesystem, memcached, etc.)

Comment: There is a no way via the Laravel Cache library... But you can do this directly from the storage service/files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the (default) file cache driver, there is no way to get the cache keys, since they are not actually stored.

The key is used to derive a file path, but it's not actually stored.

From the source:

```
public function put($key, $value, $seconds)
{
    $this->ensureCacheDirectoryExists($path = $this->path($key));

    $result = $this->files->put(
        $path, $this->expiration($seconds).serialize($value), true
    );

    if ($result !== false && $result > 0) {
        $this->ensurePermissionsAreCorrect($path);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```