# Is it possible to call C code from php

Tags: php

is it possible to call C function from 3rd party C library from a PHP5 script.
If so any link or how to do it please.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, i think the system() call will suit my purposes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but it's probably not a very good idea. One could write a small native program around the library (an executable for your system, that is). Then, you could use the php [system() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) to call that program. Then, read the output you need (if any) off the standard output?

(there may be a better way, I'm not super-familliar with PHP, but at least this *should* work.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also write PHP extensions in C.  Put very simply, an extension lets you write a function (or functions) in C, then call those functions from PHP.

This [Zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021) is a good introduction.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is written in C, so if you have some C code that you want to be able to call in PHP, the best solution is to write a PHP extension, which will allow you to expose the functionality via some new php functions.

It's been a long time since I did this, but PHP has some tools to set up the skeleton of an extension.  A good place to start is probably the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute C source-code, than it's impossible. But you can compile that code and run it from within PHP using [`system()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).