# How can i call function in a C program from php?

Tags: php, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling C/C++ library function from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php)

I have some function in C program. I want call this functions from PHP. How can I do this?

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/Inline_C/

Answer (score 1):

This is done quite often in PHP through writing a PHP extensions.

If you know some C, it should not be too hard to write a binding for a single function.

The article is quite old, but it should still be up to date on the simple functions.

http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/