# Connecting C with php/asp

Tags: php, c, web, graph-theory

I am learning to build a web application based on graph theory(Linked-In) kinda thing. So as I thought of considering PHP for getting the inputs from user via web page and using C for internal programming like adding,deleting vertex, edge to/from the graph with the help of C structures and various algorithms. So I need to know how to use C code to drive my functions while I use ASP or PHP for handling webpage.

I wish to use C preferably.

Using Xampp 1.7.4 on Windows7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862350/how-can-i-call-function-in-a-c-program-from-php

Answer (score 0):

Actually it shouldn't be that hard to code...

If you already learned C, Then I suggest you to start learning sockets.
You didn't specify the OS, So here's links to a great tutorials both
[Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/)
&
[Windows](http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/).

Now, if you don't want to use sockets, I suggest you to take a look at "Apache - Thrift".
You can communicate between functions in PHP and functions in C.

Example -

```
$shutdown->Shutdown();
```

Or

```
$points = (int*)points;
```

Good luck.