# Calling C/C++ library function from PHP - with multiple classes in a shared library

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php) and [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/) I got my first PHP extension up and running.

Here is the `config.m4` file from the article that I used (to keep it clear I kept the same `vehicles` and `car` class names from the article, although my real classes has different names):

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vehicles,
    [Whether to enable the "vehicles" extension],
    [  --enable-vehicles      Enable "vehicles" extension support])

if test $PHP_VEHICLES != "no"; then
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
    PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```

What I need now is to move o another level of code organization as follow:

a) Moving the `car`class to a common vehicle class folder with other vehicle classes (`truck`, `bus`, etc.)

b) Build a shared library will all of those classes

c) Call that shared library class from PHP

So, I would have the following directory structure like:

`vehicles -> src` = The .cpp classes and include files

`vehicles -> lib` = The vehicle.so shared library

How do I modify the `config.m4` to work with this structure, considering all the vehicle´s classes include files from the original paths and including the shared .so library to the final built.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH`did the trick. Use it as many times as you need to (for adding multiple libraries).

The final code:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vehicles,
    [Whether to enable the "vehicles" extension],
    [  --enable-vehicles      Enable "vehicles" extension support])

if test $PHP_VEHICLES != "no"; then

    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(libraryname1, /etc/whatever_path_to_library, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(libraryname2, /etc/whatever_path_to_library, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(libraryname3, /etc/whatever_path_to_library, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)

    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
    PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```