# Calling C/C++ library function from PHP - How to send a -std=c+11 to compiler

Tags: php, c++, c++11

I´m building a C++ extension to PHP, using a template of config.m4 from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479402/calling-c-c-library-function-from-php) and [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/).

I need to use the C++11 in standard to compile my classes, so I´ve used the EXTRA_FLAGS clause as:

```
EXTRA_FLAGS="-std=c++11"
```

in my config.m4. The final code:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vehicles,
    [Whether to enable the "vehicles" extension],
    [  --enable-vehicles      Enable "vehicles" extension support])

if test $PHP_VEHICLES != "no"; then
    EXTRA_FLAGS="-std=c++11"
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
    PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```

This is not working at all (the compiler does not receive the extra flags). I then assume that this EXTRA_FLAGS parameter is not related to the compiler at all, but to the script....

How can I send a flag to the g++ compiler to them him to use C++11 ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve found a solution. Here is the definitive code:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vehicles,
    [Whether to enable the "vehicles" extension],
    [  --enable-vehicles      Enable "vehicles" extension support])

if test $PHP_VEHICLES != "no"; then
    CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++0x"
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
    PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```

Make sure the `CXX_FLAGS` goes before `PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()` otherwise it won´t work.

There is also a macro called `X_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext], [mandatory])` whose code is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html) that automates that process.

Answer (score 2):

This solution not working for me. (With PHP7 extension)
I found another solution

```
if test $PHP_VEHICLES != "no"; then
   CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
   PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
   PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
   PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
   PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```

So basically The only change is `CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++0x"` change to `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"`

Comment: That is the solution for PHP7 indeed. Also makes you realize how poorly documented is extension writing for PHP

Answer (score 0):

I recently compiled my PHP extension for PHP-7.3. The configuration is similar to the snippet shown below:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vehicles, whether to enable vehicles support,
dnl Make sure that the comment is aligned:
[  --enable-vehicles          Enable vehicles support], no)

if test "$PHP_VEHICLES" != "no"; then
    CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" //other C++ linker flags go here
    PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
    PHP_SUBST(VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, VEHICLES_SHARED_LIBADD)
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(Vehicles, vehicles.cc car.cc, $ext_shared)
fi
```

Also, take a look at the `Makefile` generated from your compilation attempt. It will most likely contain information about any additional configuration required.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ext/intl` uses C++, so it's a good place to look for inspiration. For PHP 7.4 the C++ macros [got some attention](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/4acc8500acd134dfab1a2ddb83aeb39fa1033abe#diff-db329e88849d2e0aea55815e5476e70a); `ext/intl` uses a new macro `PHP_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX` with the existing `PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()`.

```
  PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
  PHP_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX(11, mandatory, PHP_INTL_STDCXX)
```

The `11` stands for the C++ version, and it supports 11, 14, and 17 at this time. The `PHP_INTL_STDCXX` variable should then be added to the link flags.